# Can anyone help me with Counter game solution?

Tags: javascript

When I try to run the input, it says that the time limit exceeded. Can anyone help me to reduce this code, thank you.

```
const counterGame = (n) => {
  let count = 0;

  for (let i = n; i > 0; i--) {
    if (Math.pow(2, i) % 1 === 0 && Math.pow(2, i) === n) {
      n /= 2;
      count++;
      if (n === 1) break;
    } else if (Math.pow(2, i) <= n) {
      n -= Math.pow(2, I);
      count++;
      if (n === 1) break;
    }
  }

  if (count % 2 === 0) {
    return 'Richard';
  } else {
    return 'Louise';
  }

};
```

Comment: Actually, It's on Hacker Rank

Comment: What's the goal of the game?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop for just checking whether n is power of 2. Check whether this helps or not.

```
const counterGame = (n) => {
if (n % 2 === 0) {
  return 'Richard';
    } else {
 return 'Louise';
}
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to iterate over the values to find if n is power of 2. You can use [Math.log2()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log2) method. Like this,

```js
function counterGame(n) {
    let move = 0;
    while(n > 1) {
        let power = parseInt(Math.log2(n));
        let max = 2**power;
        if(n === max) {
            n  = parseInt(n/2);
        } else {
            n = n - max;
        }
        move++;
    }
    if(move %2 === 0) {
        return 'Richard';
    } else {
        return 'Louise';
    }
}

console.log(counterGame(6));
console.log(counterGame(8));
```